# Location strtok definition in linux

Tags: c, linux, string

I am using Centos 5.4 Version.

I want to see the function definition of STRTOK.

Please help me how to find the location of the file which contains the definition.

I tried to locate the file string.c .I don't find the definition.

```
[sn003@localhost C]$ find / -name 'string.c' 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/string.c
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 3):

Its available in glibc git tree, see https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=string/strtok.c;hb=HEAD